# Highcharts get additional info in tool tip form JSON object

Tags: json, angularjs, highcharts, tooltip

In Angularjs framework I am using Highcharts to populate bubble chart with JSON object. In tool tip I need to add additional data from JSON object.

I have tried with the formatter function but unable to add additional data from JSON Object.

following is a Plunker link for my issue.

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/prEZypV3a3lpYtceTR7F?p=preview)

In the example there is a categories called  **Cables,
Wallplates & Boxes,
Media Distribution** when you click on these category the chart will appear.

Comment: Any one know about highcharts tool-tip formatter function. How to add additional data from JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you return string and use json.parse, which doesn't allow to use functions inside JSON. But you can use workaround. In returned json, reference any string in formatter, but in app.js define formatter function and reference this function after json.parse. It will be clear if you take look at the updated example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LfGd4N6sC0Q2tHwpPxEx?p=preview